# NHibernate: Get object by SQL Query

Tags: sql, nhibernate

Is it possible to do something like this in NHibernate?

```
Product GetSpecificProduct()
{
    return session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE price =
        $500").UniqueResult<Product>();
}
```

When I try to run this code I get:

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Object[]' to type Product.

Or do I have to use the NHibernate query language ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you have to use CreateSqlQuery, you can use the following:

```
Product GetSpecificProduct()
{
   ISQLQuery query = session.CreateSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM Products WHERE price = $500");
   Product p = query.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<Product>()).UniqueResult<Product>();
}
```

I suggest you better use ICriteria as in:

```
Product GetSpecificProduct()
{
   ICriteria c = session.CreateCriteria();
   c.Add(Expression.Eq("Price", 500));
   return c.UniqueResult<Product>();
}
```

Comment: actually the SetResultTransformer thing does not work for me ... I get an error message saying : Error - NHibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Could not find a setter for property 'Manufacturer' in class Product .............. ( This is somehow true as I don't have a property Manufacturer in the class product; the property is called ManufacturerName ; the nhibernate xml mapping specifies that ManufacturerName prop. maps to the Manufacturer column in the table )

Comment: Instead of select * you can specify the columns you want from the product table. This way SetResultTransformer will work.

Comment: @sh_kamalh I specified all columns and I still got the same error

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. Check out Entity Queries using Native SQL : http://codewut.de/content/using-native-sql-nhibernate

Comment: The link does not work any longer. "This content is no longer available on Knol."

Comment: Here's another. http://codewut.de/content/using-native-sql-nhibernate
Or just google "Entity Queries using Native SQL NHibernate" :)